# Merge List of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, dictionary-comprehension

I have 3 lists as below, which are extracted from a PDF file,

```
adID = ['9940542', '9940542', '10315065', '10315065', '11211744', '11211744', '11309685', '11309685', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12160150', '12160150']

description = ['Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Media Fee', 'Platform Fee', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)', 'Media Fee', 'Platform Fee']

spendItem = ['-1.00', '-2.00', '-1.00', '-3.00', '-290.00', '-3403.00', '-57.00', '-670.00', '709472.00', '22703.00', '-30.00', '-301.00', '-348.00', '-9376.00', '549173.00', '17573.00']
```

And I've converted these lists into a list of dictionaries as below

```
total= [{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
        {'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}},
        {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
        {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}},
        {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00'}},
        {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}},
        {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00'}},
        {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Platform Fee': '22703.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}},
        {'12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00'}},
        {'12160150': {'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}}]
```

Is there any way to iterate over this list to merge keys and values based on adID. Such as

```
Expected_result= {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00',TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00','Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00','TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}}
```

Or is there any better way to merge such data?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways. What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 3):

Using `dict.setdefault` and a simple iteration. You can also use `collection.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
total= [{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
        {'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}},
        {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
        {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}},
        {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00'}},
        {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}},
        {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00'}},
        {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Platform Fee': '22703.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00'}},
        {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}},
        {'12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00'}},
        {'12160150': {'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}}]

rsult = {}
for i in total:
    for k, v in i.items():
        rsult.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)

print(rsult)
```

**Output:**

```
{'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00',
              'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'},
 '11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00',
              'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00'},
 '11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00',
              'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00'},
 '12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00',
              'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00',
              'Media Fee': '709472.00',
              'Platform Fee': '22703.00',
              'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00',
              'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00'},
 '12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00', 'Platform Fee': '17573.00'},
 '9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00',
             'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}}
```

Comment: Much appreciated! it works. Quick question is, does the "update" method can automatically sum the values with the same keys? Say, what if there are two or three "media fees" with the same adID in the original list. Will it automatically sum all values?

Comment: No it will not. You will have use extra logic or use  `collection.Counter`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
In [18]: for d in total:
    ...:     for k,v in d.items():
    ...:         if k not in new:
    ...:             new[k]=v
    ...:         else:
    ...:             new[k].update(v)
```

---

output

```
{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'},
 '10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'},
 '11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'},
 '11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'},
 '12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00',
  'Platform Fee': '22703.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00',
  'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00',
  'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00',
  'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'},
 '12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00', 'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with 1 line of code using `python-benedict`, it's a dict subclass with many features and it's [open-source on GitHub](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict/) (I am the author).

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

```py
from benedict import benedict as bdict

data_input= [
    {'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
    {'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}},
    {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}},
    {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}},
    {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00'}},
    {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}},
    {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00'}},
    {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'Platform Fee': '22703.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00'}},
    {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}},
    {'12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00'}},
    {'12160150': {'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}}
]

data_output = bdict()
data_output.merge(*data_input)
print(data_output.dump())
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a one-liner. **Do not use in production code (use `setdefault` as in @Rakesh answer)**.

```
>>> adID = ['9940542', '9940542', '10315065', '10315065', '11211744', '11211744', '11309685', '11309685', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12103490', '12160150', '12160150']
>>> description = ['Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'Media Fee', 'Platform Fee', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)', 'Media Fee', 'Platform Fee']
>>> spendItem = ['-1.00', '-2.00', '-1.00', '-3.00', '-290.00', '-3403.00', '-57.00', '-670.00', '709472.00', '22703.00', '-30.00', '-301.00', '-348.00', '-9376.00', '549173.00', '17573.00']
```

You can easily compute `total`:

```
>>> total = [{k: {u: v}} for (k, u, v) in zip(adID, description, spendItem)]
>>> total
[{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}}, {'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}}, {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00'}}, {'10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}}, {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00'}}, {'11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}}, {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00'}}, {'11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}}, {'12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00'}}, {'12103490': {'Platform Fee': '22703.00'}}, {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00'}}, {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00'}}, {'12103490': {'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00'}}, {'12103490': {'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}}, {'12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00'}}, {'12160150': {'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}}]
```

The merged list is far more cumbersome:

```
>>> {k1: {u: v for d2 in total for k2, d2 in d2.items() for u, v in d2.items() if k2 == k1} for d1 in total for k1 in d1}
{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}, '12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00', 'Platform Fee': '22703.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}, '12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00', 'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}, '10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}, '11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}, '11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}}
```

This is very slow because you need to extract the keys and then to find the items matching those keys.

It is easier to write, but not really faster, in one step:

```
>>> {k1: {u: v for (k2, u, v) in zip(adID, description, spendItem) if k2 == k1} for k1 in set(adID)}
{'9940542': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-2.00'}, '12103490': {'Media Fee': '709472.00', 'Platform Fee': '22703.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-30.00', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Platofrm Fee)': '-301.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-348.00', 'TrueView Budget Adjust (Media Fee)': '-9376.00'}, '12160150': {'Media Fee': '549173.00', 'Platform Fee': '17573.00'}, '10315065': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-1.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3.00'}, '11309685': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-57.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-670.00'}, '11211744': {'Invalid Adjust(Platform Fee)': '-290.00', 'Invalid Adjust(Media Fee)': '-3403.00'}}
```